# How to to add watermark to videos in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, watermark

I want to add watermark to videos in flutter before downloading the videos from firebase. There is a question similar to mine that is being answered, but the package suggested is only available for ios, I want for both android and ios. I have seen FFmpeg but the commands are confusing and don't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to add a watermark before downloading unless we can add a watermark while uploading that video itself.

I just found a package `video_manipulation`. You can just refer to the example of implementing the Watermark after downloading that video.

Reference: https://pub.dev/packages/video_manipulation#usage

Comment: Maybe there's the possibility of uploading the video with and without the watermark to allow its both usages

Comment: But the package you suggested is only for ios.

Comment: Yeah. I too searched for it. Can you give FFmpeg the last try?
Watermark Command: https://gist.github.com/bennylope/d5d6029fb63648582fed2367ae23cfd6
FFmpeg: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg